# How to make 2 routers work with powerlines

Tags: router, connection, powerline-networking

Good afternoon kind sirs, got a newbie question for you.

I got a router (R1) that serves as the network provider, and another old router (R2) I want to use as a "network switch" and WiFi repeater, since it is more powerful than R1 despite being older. I set up both routers, and everything works fine when R1 and R2 are connected directly through a LAN port: R1 provides the connectivity, R2 recieves and repeats the signal through WiFi. R2 is given a static IP.

Problem is I want to move R2 to a better position and give it connectivity through a powerline, and that's when it stops working - it is connected, the eth signal is working, but there is no connectivity. I cannot access its configuration nor use its WiFi.

Why on earth should it not be working, since I am just giving it the connectivity from another source?

Powerline works fine on the computers I own, just the R2 doesn't seem to accept it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the powerline adapters? Are they both setup together and sycned? I don't know the model so cannot advise on the process but you normally hold the first button down for 2-3 seconds and repeat on the next one.

The other thing to try is a laptop connected to the powerline and see if you get an IP / connectivity.

Comment: They are setup and synced. Laptop works fine when connected.
If it helps, they are TP-LINK powerlines and the router model is Netgear TD-W8980.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have separate power circuits for different parts of your house, especially if you have an older house that's been upgraded.  See if you can trace the electricals, and try several outlets.  Test, test, test.

Comment: Tried connecting powerline and R2 to an outlet that I'm certain to be working - the one I am using this laptop with. Still no sign of life.